# FlaskWebsocket Emit is not Broadcasted to the connections

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, flask-socketio

I would like to do a WebSocket broadcast with Flask flask_socketio. What I want to achieve is to have the server telling the client to rerender every 5s using the new information provided by the server. In order to achieve this, I set up a socket connection, then I use a daemon thread to try to broadcast something to the clients every 5s. However, only the Emit within `@socketio.on('connect')` is working. Whereas the Emit function called within the daemon thread does nothing. What I can confirm is that the connection is established, as the first Emit does update the frontend but seemingly the server is not broadcasting the 5s message or something blocks the message from reaching the frontend.

Attached is my code:

```
import time
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, join_room, leave_room

from flask_cors import CORS
from flask import request


import threading
import eventlet
from eventlet import wsgi

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret_key'
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins='*')

# Track connected clients
connected_clients = set()

# Define WebSocket event handlers
@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    print('Client connected, ID=', request.sid)
    connected_clients.add(request.sid)
    emit('custom_event', 'Hello There!')  # Send a message to the client
    # emit('heartbeat', 'beat')
    
@socketio.on('disconnect')
def handle_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')
    connected_clients.remove(request.sid)

heartbeat_msg = ["hdofajosjdof", "I'm still here", "Hey You!"]
# Thread function to send "I'm still here" message every 5 seconds
@socketio.on('heartbeat')
def send_heartbeat():
    i = 0
    while True:
        for client in connected_clients:
            print('sending heartbeat to', client)
            socketio.server.manager.emit('custom_event', i, '/')
            # socketio.emit('custom_event', heartbeat_msg[i%3])
            i += 1
        time.sleep(10)

# Start the heartbeat thread
heartbeat_thread = threading.Thread(target=send_heartbeat)
heartbeat_thread.daemon = True
heartbeat_thread.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
#     print('Running')
    socketio.run(app, debug=True) 
    # wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(("127.0.0.1", 5000)), app, debug=True)
```

Comment: Why are you calling `socketio.server.manager.emit()`? That is an internal method. You should stick to the documentation, if something isn't documented, you are not supposed to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem with my src code is because threading is not enabled for my socketio application.

```
import time
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, join_room, leave_room

from flask_cors import CORS
from flask import request

import random

import threading
import eventlet
from eventlet import wsgi

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'your_secret_key'
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins='*', async_mode='threading') # <======== adding async_mode works

# Track connected clients
connected_clients = set()

# Define WebSocket event handlers
@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    print('Client connected, ID=', request.sid)
    connected_clients.add(request.sid)
    emit('custom_event', 'Hello There!')  # Send a message to the client
    
@socketio.on('disconnect')
def handle_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')
    connected_clients.remove(request.sid)

heartbeat_msg = ["hdofajosjdof", "I'm still here", "Hey You!", "test", 'ajslkdfj', 'Test123']

# Thread function to send "I'm still here" message every 5 seconds
def send_heartbeat():    
    while True:
        for client in connected_clients:
            print('sending heartbeat to', client)
            i = random.randint(0, len(heartbeat_msg) -1)
            # socketio.server.manager.emit('custom_event', heartbeat_msg[i], '/')
            socketio.emit('custom_event', heartbeat_msg[i%len(heartbeat_msg)], to=client)
            
            time.sleep(10)

# Start the heartbeat thread
heartbeat_thread = threading.Thread(target=send_heartbeat)
heartbeat_thread.daemon = True
heartbeat_thread.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True) 
    # wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(("127.0.0.1", 5000)), app, debug=True)
```